# VBA Excel - If a certain value in the column matches my criteria then display a message

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that keeps running in the background while i am working on the excel sheet.

Function: if a certain cell in an entire column = Now() then display a message box.

Can someone please share the code for this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? you mean `Now()` as in the formula ? or cell value time value equals to now ? Anyway, read in to `Worksheet_Change` event, and use `Target.Column` to see if the cell modifed falls inside a certain column

Comment: [Please read how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You would not want a function constantly running.  Do some research on Worksheet_Change function, which would be on that worksheet module.  Then the function would only run when a change to that worksheet occurs.  You can trap the column or cell you want to write code for.

Comment: Now () refers to the time value. 
Sure I will look into worksheet_change thing.

Basically the code I want to write will do this. Whenever a cell in, say, column "B" equals in time value Now (), the sheet should automatically display a msgbox saying "Please call the customer".
This sheet will be used by the Customer Services Team.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your worksheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
' for a certain column - in this case G
    Dim Arr
        Arr = Split(Target.Address, "$")
        If Arr(1) = "G" Then
            Beep
            MsgBox "You have selected column G..."
        End If

' for a certain row - in this case 2
    If Right(Target.Address, 2) = "$2" Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "You have selected Row 2..."
    End If

' for a certain cell - in this case A3
    If Target.Address = "$A$3" Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "You have selected Cell A3..."
    End If


End Sub
```